# Usercontrol access Javascript from a Content's Page's Master Page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls, master-pages

Hello all I have a problem. I have a masterpage that all of my Content pages inherit from. Within this masterpage I have a script tag pointing to the Javascript file folder `~/Scripts/validation.js`

On my content pages I use different usercontrols that require the use of many of the functions within the `validation.js` file however if I dont put the `<script>` tag and the Javascript functions within a contentholder on the contentpage the usercontrols do not see these functions and I get errors like `OnNameValidation` is not defined.

Of course I can copy the Javascript code into all of the pages but that's 30+ pages and a maintenance nightmare if I find a bug in one of the Javascript functions.

So the question (if you haven't already figured out from my long dissertation) is how can I declare the script tag with the path to the validation.js file so that contentpages and their usercontrols etc. can access the functions/code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do should work, so I suspect that the path to your javascript file is wrong (without seeing your html code I can only assume).  Keep in mind that you can only reference the javascript file like this: "~/Scripts/validation.js" if you have the link in a HEAD runat="server" tag.  Without the runat="server" it won't find the file.  You would have to do something like "../scripts/validation.js"

As a test I would try to call your javascript function in the masterpage, so you can rule out a bad file reference.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up this tip from ScottGu [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx).

Add this to you user control which enables Intellisense in user controls but always evaluates false:

```
<% if (false) { %>
   <script src="/Scripts/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you are assigning for your js file is probably not matching in all the pages.

```
script src="../JavaScript/Scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js"
```

It should have something like above this if you have separate folder for Scripts, MasterPages, Pages & Controls.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing this in my site by going to the Source code on the master page and putting the following in the head and outside of the ContentPlaceHolder.

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script src="CP.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```